# Nested runs using MLflowClient

Tags: python, mlflow

In `mlflow`, you can run nested runs using the fluent projects API which are collapsable in the UI. E.g. by using the following code (see [this](https://databricks.com/blog/2018/11/21/mlflow-v0-8-0-features-improved-experiment-ui-and-deployment-tools.html) for UI support):

```
with mlflow.start_run(nested=True):
  mlflow.log_param("mse", 0.10)
  mlflow.log_param("lr", 0.05)
  mlflow.log_param("batch_size", 512)
  with mlflow.start_run(nested=True):
    mlflow.log_param("max_runs", 32)
    mlflow.log_param("epochs", 20)
    mlflow.log_metric("acc", 98)
    mlflow.log_metric("rmse", 98)
  mlflow.end_run()
```

Due to database connection issues, I want to use a single mlflow client across my application.

How can I stack runs, e.g. for hyperparameter optimization, using created runs via `MlflowClient().create_run()`?

Comment: Here is a full example that uses MLFlow and Optuna with parallel MLFlow runs: https://simonhessner.de/mlflow-optuna-parallel-hyper-parameter-optimization-and-logging/

Answer (score 7):

It is a bit complicated to achieve, but I found a way by looking into the [Fluent Tracking Interface](https://www.mlflow.org/docs/latest/_modules/mlflow/tracking/fluent.html) that is used when you directly use the `mlflow` import.

In the `start_run` function you can see that a `nested_run` is just defined by setting a specific tag `mlflow.utils.mlflow_tags.MLFLOW_PARENT_RUN_ID`. Just set this to the `run.info.run_id` value of your parent run and it will be shown correctly in the UI.

Here is an example:

```py
from mlflow.tracking import MlflowClient
from mlflow.utils.mlflow_tags import MLFLOW_PARENT_RUN_ID

client = MlflowClient()
try:
    experiment = client.create_experiment("test_nested")
except:
    experiment = client.get_experiment_by_name("test_nested").experiment_id
parent_run = client.create_run(experiment_id=experiment)
client.log_param(parent_run.info.run_id, "who", "parent")

child_run_1 = client.create_run(
        experiment_id=experiment,
        tags={
            MLFLOW_PARENT_RUN_ID: parent_run.info.run_id
        }
    )
client.log_param(child_run_1.info.run_id, "who", "child 1")

child_run_2 = client.create_run(
        experiment_id=experiment,
        tags={
            MLFLOW_PARENT_RUN_ID: parent_run.info.run_id
        }
    )
client.log_param(child_run_2.info.run_id, "who", "child 2")
```

In case you're wondering: The run name can also be specified that way, using the `mlflow.utils.mlflow_tags.MLFLOW_RUN_NAME` tag.